# I have a JSON table, how can I create a sql table with this information in PLSQL?

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm working with PLSQL and I have this JSON table (first variable),
How can I insert this data into a sql table, i have already try this, but i have SQL statement ignored error:

```
CREATE TABLE Prueba_ins_json (
        userId number(3),
        id number(3),
        title VARCHAR2(200),
        body VARCHAR2(800)
    );
DECLARE
  json_prueba VARCHAR(5000) := '[
                              {
                                "userId": 1,
                                "id": 1,
                                "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
                                "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
                              },
                              {
                                "userId": 1,
                                "id": 2,
                                "title": "qui est esse",
                                "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
                              },
                              {
                                "userId": 1,
                                "id": 3,
                                "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
                                "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
                              },
                              {
                                "userId": 1,
                                "id": 4,
                                "title": "eum et est occaecati",
                                "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
                              }
                              ]';
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Prueba_ins_json
  SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE( json_prueba, '$[*]'
                              columns(
                                userId, id, title, body
                              )
                            );

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to provide `PATH`(*preferably along with data types*) clause such as

```
INSERT INTO Prueba_ins_json
SELECT *
  FROM JSON_TABLE(json_prueba,
                  '$[*]' COLUMNS(
                                  userId INT           PATH '$.userId',
                                  id     INT           PATH '$.id',
                                  title  VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.title',
                                  body   VARCHAR2(800) PATH '$.body'
                                 )
                  );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=56e3e3a1a8fa4ee06acf5806cfbacdb1)</kbd>

**Edit** (*as you're using DB 11g*) **:**

You can alternatively use `XMLTABLE()` along with `APEX_JSON.TO_XMLTYPE()` instead such as

```
INSERT INTO Prueba_ins_json
WITH t(jsCol) AS
(
 SELECT '<your_JSON_value>' 
   FROM dual 
)
SELECT userId, id, title, body
  FROM t,
       XMLTABLE('/json/row'
                PASSING APEX_JSON.TO_XMLTYPE(jsCol)
                COLUMNS 
                  userId INT           PATH 'userId',
                  id     INT           PATH 'id',
                  title  VARCHAR2(200) PATH 'title',
                  body   VARCHAR2(800) PATH 'body'
               )
```

Comment: Nope, it seems that the problem is in the query, look: i copied and pasted your answer and i still get the same error, in the FROM line: SQL statement ignored.

Comment: I m using version 11G

Comment: I already suspected the version to be 12c-, since JSON_TABLE function starts with version(12.1.0.2) @GasparGiménez , but there are some other techniques yet in 11g

Comment: Is there another way to do the same in this version? How can I do it?

Comment: plis im waiting :')

Comment: Barbaros, can you explain me how it works? Thank you very much!

Comment: Since XMLTABLE has a similar logic with JSON_TABLE in order to pass sub-values like a tree structure, and [APEX_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm) special format to specifically be designed as in the document @GasparGiménez

Comment: In the first answer to this question (assuming Oracle 12.1 or higher) - the path is indeed mandatory, but the data type is not. (It is still a good practice, but not required.)